# Extended WPF Toolkit DateTimePicker Drop-Down Interval

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetimepicker, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have installed the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit#extended-wpf-toolkit) and I am trying to change the interval in the `DateTimePicker` time picker (so it is half an hour instead of an hour). I've tried using the `TimeInterval` property [as shown here](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/TimePicker), but no such property exists. What am I doing wrong?

```
xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"

<wpfTool:DateTimePicker TimeInterval="00:30:00" Name="dateTimePicker1" HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="250" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,60,0,0"/>
```

Comment: DataTimePicker and TimePicker are different classes.

Comment: @Clemens What about the DateTimePicker then? How do I set the time interval?

Comment: No Idea. It's unclear what you are actually asking. In a TimePicker the TimeInterval sets the interval between the time items in the dropdown. In a DateTimePicker the items are days. I guess you can't change that to half days or whatever.

Comment: @Clemens DateTimePicker has separate dates and times with dropdown lists. I need to change the interval exactly for the time part.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimePicker` and `TimePicker` are different controls that do not expose the same properties.

- [`DateTimePicker` properties documentation](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker#properties)
- [`TimePicker` properties documentation](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/TimePicker#properties)

The `DateTimePicker` does not have a property for customizing the time interval. Internally it contains a `TimePicker` in its control template, but it does not actually assign or expose its `TimeInterval` property, as you can see from [the default style on GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/9b694aa76c399bea71b08da470d3deadfb0c2d79/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/DateTimePicker/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml#L213).

```
<local:TimePicker x:Name="PART_TimeUpDown"
                  Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
                  Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"
                  Format="{TemplateBinding TimeFormat}"
                  FormatString="{TemplateBinding TimeFormatString}"
                  Kind="{Binding Kind, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  Minimum="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  Maximum="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  ClipValueToMinMax="{Binding ClipValueToMinMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  IsUndoEnabled="{Binding IsUndoEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding TimePickerAllowSpin}"
                  Step="{TemplateBinding Step}"
                  ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding TimePickerShowButtonSpinner}"
                  Watermark="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermark}"
                  WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermarkTemplate}"
                  Visibility="{TemplateBinding TimePickerVisibility}" />
```

What you could do is copy and change this default style and add a value for the `TimeInterval` property. However, there are lots of dependencies to resources in this style, so the easiest way is to [copy the whole resource dictionary](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/tree/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/DateTimePicker/Themes) and adapt it, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:themes1="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
                    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">

   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;component/Themes/Aero2/Common.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;component/Themes/Aero2/Glyphs.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

   <xctk:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter" />
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
   <xctk:BorderThicknessConverter x:Key="BorderThicknessConverter" />

   <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultWatermarkTemplate">
      <ContentControl Margin="0,0,3,0"
                      Content="{Binding}"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
   </DataTemplate>

   <Style x:Key="DateTimePickerToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
               <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                  <xctk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome"
                                     CornerRadius="0"
                                     RenderChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xctk:DateTimePicker}}"
                                     RenderEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xctk:DateTimePicker}}"
                                     RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                     RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}">

                     <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                        <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Margin="5"
                              IsHitTestVisible="False">
                           <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                                 Width="9"
                                 Height="5"
                                 Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                 Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"
                                 Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Grid>
                     </Grid>
                  </xctk:ButtonChrome>
               </Grid>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                     <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#AFAFAF" />
                  </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>


   <!--  ===============================================================================  -->
   <!--  DateTimePicker  -->
   <!--  ===============================================================================  -->

   <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes1:ResourceKeys.ControlNormalBorderKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,1" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
      <Setter Property="TimeWatermarkTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWatermarkTemplate}" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWatermarkTemplate}" />
      <Setter Property="CalendarWidth" Value="178" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
               <Border>
                  <Grid>
                     <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <xctk:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding AllowSpin}"
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            ButtonSpinnerLocation="{TemplateBinding ButtonSpinnerLocation}"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}">
                           <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                                  MinWidth="20"
                                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                  AcceptsReturn="False"
                                                  Background="Transparent"
                                                  BorderThickness="0"
                                                  FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                                  FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                                  FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                                  FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                                  FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                  IsTabStop="True"
                                                  IsUndoEnabled="{Binding IsUndoEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                  TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}"
                                                  Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                  TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                                                  TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                                  Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"
                                                  WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" />
                        </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="_calendarToggleButton"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      Background="White"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerToggleButtonStyle}"
                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowDropDownButton,
                                                                   Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                     </Grid>
                     <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                            IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_calendarToggleButton}"
                            StaysOpen="False"
                            ToolTip="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                        <Popup.Resources>
                           <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                              <Style.Triggers>
                                 <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                 </Trigger>
                              </Style.Triggers>
                           </Style>
                        </Popup.Resources>
                        <Border Padding="3"
                                Background="{StaticResource PanelBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource PopupDarkBorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                           <StackPanel>
                              <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calendar"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        DisplayMode="{Binding CalendarDisplayMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                 <Calendar.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                                       <Viewbox Width="{Binding CalendarWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}}}">
                                          <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                             <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                                                           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                           BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                           Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}" />
                                          </StackPanel>
                                       </Viewbox>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                 </Calendar.Template>
                              </Calendar>
                              <xctk:TimePicker x:Name="PART_TimeUpDown"
                                               AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding TimePickerAllowSpin}"
                                               Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
                                               ClipValueToMinMax="{Binding ClipValueToMinMax, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"
                                               Format="{TemplateBinding TimeFormat}"
                                               FormatString="{TemplateBinding TimeFormatString}"
                                               IsUndoEnabled="{Binding IsUndoEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Kind="{Binding Kind, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Maximum="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Minimum="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding TimePickerShowButtonSpinner}"
                                               Step="{TemplateBinding Step}"
                                               TimeInterval="00:30:00"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding TimePickerVisibility}"
                                               Watermark="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermark}"
                                               WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermarkTemplate}"
                                               Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                           </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                     </Popup>
                  </Grid>
               </Border>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes1:ResourceKeys.ControlMouseOverBorderKey}}" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger>
                     <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding AllowTextInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                  </MultiDataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes1:ResourceKeys.ControlSelectedBorderKey}}" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                     <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" />
                  </Trigger>
                  <MultiTrigger>
                     <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="ShowButtonSpinner" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="ShowDropDownButton" Value="False" />
                     </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Setter TargetName="PART_Spinner" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BorderThicknessConverter}}" />
                  </MultiTrigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Include this resource dictionary in your application resources or another resources section, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="DateTimePickerResources.xaml"/>
```

As you can see, this brings in lots of code for a simple change, so please consider if this effort is is feasible for you, or if it might be better to live with this limitation of the `DateTimePicker` control.

Answer (score -1):

In code you can set the interval to show in the DateTimePicker.
For example

```
TPSalida.TimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
```

[image]